# Alternative of GlusterFS for Hardware

Tags: hardware, cluster, grid

When you look at my question title then you might think I am going to ask for alternative of GlusterFS in the space of storage,but what I am looking for the hint is basically I want to find software that can do the same like gluster but for clustering the power resources

The idea is like virtualization pool.where we can link some VMs in different physical computer as one big computer pool,but the problem with this approach is we have to provide hardware with processor Virtualization support but how about with the old hardware with no VT Technology support

If there's anyone here knows about what kind of software that I can use to do such a hardware clustering regardless application software inside please let me know

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, what you're looking for doesn't exist. There exist a plethora of really great clustering products, but they all require special considerations to be taken when writing and compiling the code.